# How to get Background title in BDD Specflow C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, nunit, bdd, specflow

How do I get the name of the pre test condition "Background" tag in a Feature using Specflow + Nunit in C #?

I can get the name of the "Feature" like this:

```
return FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title;
```

And the name of the "Scenario" like this:

```
 return ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title;
```

I also need to get the name of the "Background", or check if it exists.

```
Feature: FeatureTest
    Description Feature...

Background: Get Background name or check it exists (Return It)
    ...Given, And

Scenario: Scenario Test
    ...Given, And
```

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

The reason you can't access the Background, is because the steps contained within it are duplicated at runtime across all of the scenarios within a feature, effectively removing the background.

#### The Answer:

Generally speaking, Backgrounds do not have a title:

```
Ability: Adding and Removing items from the basket

   As a customer,
   I want the ability to add and remove items from my basket
   In order to choose the items that I want to purchase from the site

 Background:
   Given I have logged in as a customer
   And I visit the "Clothing" page

 Scenario: Adding items to my basket
   When I add "Black Jeans" to my basket in size "M"
   Then the total should be "£9.99"

 Scenario: Removing items from the basket
   Given I have added an item of clothing to my basket
   When I empty my basket
   Then the total should be "£0.00"
```

The Background steps get duplicated across the scenarios within the feature, meaning that the scenarios in my example are effectively:

```
 Scenario: Adding items to my basket
   Given I have logged in as a customer
   And I visit the "Clothing" page
   When I add "Black Jeans" to my basket in size "M"
   Then the total should be "£9.99"

 Scenario: Removing items from the basket
   Given I have logged in as a customer
   And I visit the "Clothing" page
   Given I have added an item of clothing to my basket
   When I empty my basket
   Then the total should be "£0.00"
```

Why would you need to access the Background description, if what you're actually testing is covered by the Scenario description?

That is why currently they do not offer this as a feature. It's additional information within a file that allow ease of reading and understanding of what is actually being tested - but if your steps are descriptive enough, do you need a description for the setup for a test?

Comment: I need this information to write logs in a .html report, for organization reasons to the user who does not have access to the Feature, to facilitate reading or identifying the steps, I currently record all the steps making the report a little redundant ... Example: [link](http://extentreports.com/samples/extent-bdd.html)

Answer (score 0):

This information is currently not available at runtime in SpecFlow. Please open an issue on GitHub for this, that we can potentially add this in later versions.

But generally it is bad practice to depend on such fragile (potential often changing magic strings).
Better way would be to check for a tag on Scenario or Feature level.

Also be aware, that you don't know at runtime, that you are currently executing parts of the background. There is no difference between these Given steps and the Given steps of your scenario.

Comment: I need to register the execution result in an html report, but the features do not always have background, so it works dynamically, I need to check at least if the background exists. Example: [Link](http://extentreports.com/samples/extent-bdd.html)